# Div element is on new line without <br> but i don't want to do that

Tags: html, css, text-align

Im making a web page and I have a header with a menu option on the left, a title in the middle and a link to the logIn/signUp page. This an img: https://ibb.co/z6R1h6w
Unfortunately the login and signup link on the left hand side is on a new line and i don't want that to happen. I have tried the following:

```
  float: right;

  text-align: right;

  vertical-align: text-top !important;
```

Code: https://hastebin.com/pesuhemulo.xml

cheers in advance

Comment: Show a snippet with that particular issue, that you have.

Comment: https://ibb.co/z6R1h6w

the login/signup link is lower than i want it

Comment: I mean HTML and CSS code snippet.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/pesuhemulo.xml. if i put it in here then it says i have too much code

Comment: First up, `divs` are block level elements that will start on a new line be default. You need to style them to stop that behaviour. Please provide your code here as a [MCVE], reducing the code to just enough to replicate the problem. If you are getting an error saying you have too much code, then, in all likelihood, you have not made enough effort in reducing the scope of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use float layouts anymore, they are kind of outdated for most use-cases.

I recommend using [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_flexbox.asp). Here's a small example:

```css
header, header #menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

#menu li {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<p>Menu</p>
<p>Image</p>
<ul id="menu">
<li>link A</li>
<li>link B</li>
</ul>
</header>
```

You can add `nowrap` to flex-flow in order to make sure they are ALWAYS in the same row.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a css grid. In the snippet example below you can see the center column stretches out over the unused width and all 3 divs are on 1 row:

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
}

header .header-title {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

header .left {
  text-align: left;
}

header .right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">Nav</div>
  <div class="header-title">Header</div>
  <div class="right">Login</div>
</header>
```

Modify the `grid-template-columns` to change the width of your columns.